# Show div and hide others with ToggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a question regarding the toggle functionality of jQuery. I want to achieve that if I click on the arrow the content becomes visible and all other contents are hidden.

I use this JS code to toggle the class within a generic way:

```
$(function () {         
    $('.main-diff .blue-bg .arc_arrow').click(function () {                                                     
        $(this).toggleClass('arc_arrow--displayed');
        $(this).parent().next('.matchfooter').toggleClass('matchfooter--displayed');                
    });
});
```

To look at my HTML code and CSS you could have a look here: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2omxw3p9/)

I tried to add `$('.matchfooter').removeClass('matchfooter--displayed');` but that does not hide the content anymore if I click again on the same arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `toggle` you can just add class and remove it on clicking others.

```
$(function () {
    $('.main-diff .blue-bg .arc_arrow').click(function () {
        //Hide others        
        $('.main-diff .blue-bg .arc_arrow').not(this).removeClass('arc_arrow--displayed');
        $('.main-diff .blue-bg .arc_arrow').not(this).parent().next('.matchfooter').removeClass('matchfooter--displayed');

        $(this).addClass('arc_arrow--displayed');
        $(this).parent().next('.matchfooter').addClass('matchfooter--displayed');
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oq7y74nm/3/)

Comment: Thanks! Indeed this is also possible but I still have the problem of hiding the `matchfooter` by clicking the arrow in the div which showed the content.

Comment: Actually what you need to do. Closing it by clicking others or closing it by clicking it again?

Comment: What I need is both ;)

Comment: Updated my fiddle for your required.Check it.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! Exactly what I want!

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove class from other elements, which can be achieved using `.not()` selector.

```
$('.main-diff .blue-bg .arc_arrow').click(function () {
    //Hide others        
    $('.main-diff .blue-bg .arc_arrow').not(this).removeClass('arc_arrow--displayed');
    $('.main-diff .blue-bg .arc_arrow').not(this).parent().next('.matchfooter').removeClass('matchfooter--displayed');

    $(this).toggleClass('arc_arrow--displayed');
    $(this).parent().next('.matchfooter').toggleClass('matchfooter--displayed');
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/oq7y74nm/1/)

Comment: This is awesome! But once you open the content you cannot hide it. You can only hide the content by clicking on another arc_arrow. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @Rotan075, What exactly you need?

Comment: What I need is closing the content by clicking other arrows and by clicking it again. Now if the `'matchfooter'` is visible and you want to close it by clicking it again only the arrow class is changed and the content is not hidden. To be more clear: click the first content open -> click on the same arrow -> the content will not be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved your issue, just change the jquery code with following and try again :-

```
$(function () {         
    $('.main-diff .blue-bg .arc_arrow').click(function () {                                                     
        $(this).toggleClass('arc_arrow--displayed');
        $(".matchfooter").removeClass("matchfooter--displayed");
        $(this).parent().next('.matchfooter').toggleClass('matchfooter--displayed');                
    });
});
```